# UWP apps crashing when using multiple views

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a couple of different UWP apps in development right now, and they both crash when using multiple views with the message:

```
A COM call to an ASTA was blocked because the call chain originated in or passed through another ASTA. This call pattern is deadlock-prone and disallowed by apartment call control.
```

Neither app crashes with only one view.

The crash can happen when the app is in use, or if just sitting in the background.

I am as certain as I can be that I'm using the correct dispatcher per view, up until the crash, both views work fine. I start up the new view in the "OnLaunched" method in my App.xaml.cs file, like this:

```
   CoreApplicationView newView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();


                await newView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {

//sort out new view here.
});
```

I pass "newView" to the new Page and only ever use that to get a dispatcher to run UI stuff.

That the app can simply crash in the background maybe makes me think that Windows 10 is trying to sleep the app, and the problem come there perhaps?

Love to get to the bottom of this, any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Garry

Comment: Did you use third part framework in your app, for example,prism? Could you please test the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MultipleViews) on your side if the sample can reproduce  your issue?

Comment: I've been doing some digging around and now I can reproduce the problem only if the AdControl from Microsoft is present in the XAML. If I take out the AdControl, no crashes, if I put in the AdControl, I'll frequently get a crash. Is it possible the AdControl does not support multiple pages?

Comment: Did you mean you put the AdControl in the new view (not the main view) will lead this issue? Could you please using a AdControl with test value for testing?

Comment: Yes, my app can create any number of views using CoreApplication.CreateNewView();. When I'm just using one view, everything seems OK, but when I create a new view from the task bar menu of my app, that crash often happens. What do you mean by a test value? I've got the ad set up with ids etc. from my Windows Developer Console.

Comment: I tested with the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MultipleViews) but cannot reproduce your issue. Please provide your testing environment and debug  it to provide the relative code snippet. The above code snippet you provided has nothing wrong.